# Permutation group is a subgroup of another permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I'm trying to understand, how is it possible to know if $S_3= \{ (), (1,2), (2,3), (1,3), (1,2,3), (1,3,2)\}$ is a subgroup of $S_{27}$.

I tried to calculate $27!$ and see if it's divisible by $3! = 6$, to check if it satisfies Lagrange's Theorem, but $27!$ is a very large number.

( + Quick Second question : how to check associativity in permutation groups, as it's one of the condition for it to be a group ?)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You don't need to actually compute $27!$. You just know this number is equal to $1\times 2\times 3\times 4\times...\times 27$, so it is obviously divisible by $1\times 2\times 3$. Anyway, Lagrange's theorem is only a necessary condition, not a sufficient one. You can't just say that if the order of a group $H$ divides the order of $G$ then $H\leq G$.

Comment: If $n<m$ then $S_n$ is a subgroup of $S_m$ (just consider permutations which fix $\{n+1, \cdots, m\}$).

Comment: In fact more can be said: $\;S_n\;$ can be **embedded** in $\;A_{n+2}\le S_{n+2}\;$, and thus the answer in this case is clear. Yet **formally** we could say the elements in each group are different from each other and thus one of them cannot even be a *subset* of the other one, let alone a subgroup.

Comment: @Mark Indeed so...but it is almost never the case that $\;S_n\;$ is defined by means of the full group of bijections $\;\Bbb N\to\Bbb N\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I know. It just can be an option if somebody just begins to learn group theory and is not feeling comfortable with identifying embeddings with real subgroups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $S_n$ is the set, under composition, of all bijections from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ to $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Thus consider the map $\varphi: \{1,2,3\}\to\{1,\dots, 27\}$ given by $\varphi(x)=x$ for $x\in\{1,2,3\}$, viewing the output as an element of $\{1,\dots,27\}$. Can you see how to extend this to an embedding of $S_3$ into $S_{27}$?

---

Associativity of permutations follows from associativity of bijections.

Comment: Thank you ! Would you mind explaining the part of associativity please. thanks

Comment: You're welcome, @WassimJaoui. Let $f,g,h$ be bijections on a set $X$ to itself. Let $x\in X$. Then $$\begin{align} ((f\circ g)\circ h)(x)&=(f\circ g)(h(x))\\ &=f(g(h(x)))\\ &=f((g\circ h)(x))\\ &=(f\circ(g\circ h))(x).\end{align}$$ Hence $(f\circ g)\circ h=f\circ(g\circ h)$ since $x$ was arbitrary.

Comment: @Wassim Jaoui, I like not to miss a chance to remind that abstract groups ("$G$") have among their properties the associativity *just because* their same definition is precisely patterned upon the properties of the set of bijections on a whatever set $X$ under map composition, and associativity is possibly the foremost of them. Your case is just the special one for $X=\{1,\dots,27\}$

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, $S_3\cap S_{27}=\emptyset$ (a map on a set of $3$ elements can't never be equal to one on a set of $27$ elements, isn't it?), and hence asking whether "$S_3\le S_{27}$" is an abuse of language. The correct closest question to that, rather, is whether $S_3\hookrightarrow S_{27}$. Now, consider the map ($X:=\{1,\dots,27\}$):

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \epsilon: S_3&\longrightarrow& S_{27} \\
  \sigma&\longmapsto& \epsilon_\sigma: X &\longrightarrow X \\
  &&i&\longmapsto \epsilon_\sigma(i) \\
\tag 1
\end{alignat}

defined by

\begin{alignat}{2}
 &\epsilon_\sigma(i):=\sigma(i), &&\space\space\text{for} \space i=1,2,3 \\
 &\epsilon_\sigma(i):=i, &&\space\space\text{for} \space i=4,5,\dots,27 \\
\tag 2
\end{alignat}

You can prove that:

1. for every $\sigma\in S_3$, we have indeed $\epsilon_\sigma\in S_{27}$, so the writing $(1)$ makes sense;
2. $\epsilon_\sigma=\epsilon_\tau \Rightarrow \sigma=\tau$, so $\epsilon$ is injective;
3. for every $\sigma,\tau\in S_3$, we have that $\epsilon_{\sigma\tau}=\epsilon_\sigma\epsilon_\tau$, so $\epsilon$ is a group homomorphism.

Therefore, yes: $S_3\hookrightarrow S_{27}$. (Actually, with the same construction you get for free the generalization: $S_m\hookrightarrow S_n$ as soon as $n>m$; or even wider: $S_Y\hookrightarrow S_X$ for every set $X$ and $Y\subset X$.)